# JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces, Tree dynamic ID to hide/show multiple panels

Tags: java, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.0

I have a tree structure, I want to show/hide multiple panels on selection

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{bean.root}" var="node"  dynamic="true" cache="false" animate="true" selectionMode="single"  
        selection="#{bean.selectedNode}">
        <p:ajax event="select" update=":MainPageForm:dataPanel" listener="#{bean.onNodeSelect}" /> 
            <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
            <p:commandLink id="DYNAMIC ID" style="font-size:15px; width:170px; height:30px;" value="#{node}" />  
        </p:treeNode>
```

for now I am trying to set dynamic id on each node using '`#{node}`' but throws an exception
I am using JQuery in my app so right now I am trying to hide/show using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

it is not very clear what you want to accomplish, but do not use dynamic ids.

maybe this?

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{bean.root}" var="node"  dynamic="true" cache="false" animate="true" selectionMode="single"  
    selection="#{bean.selectedNode}">
    <p:ajax event="select" process="@form" update="@form"/>
    <p:treeNode>#{node}</p:treeNode>
</p:tree>

<h:panelGroup id="details">
    <p:panel header="details1" rendered="#{bean.selectedNode.data.type == 'hw'}">
        <span>i am an hardware: #{bean.selectedNode.data}</span>
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel header="details2" rendered="#{bean.selectedNode.data.type == 'sw'}">
        <span>i am a software: #{bean.selectedNode.data}</span>
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: what is data in this?? `selectedNode.data`

Comment: `#{bean.selectedNode.data}` used **outside** `p:tree` is the same as `#{node}` used **inside** `p:tree`